# Is EMC (FCC and EU) testing performed as sold or as used?

Tags: rf, emc, fcc

I have a prototype that inserts a fairly weak ISM band RF signal (HF/VHF) as a way of detecting a connection between two metal objects without there being a DC return path (Ideally I would use TDR but I can't do that on my budget at home).

I don't think it would be classed as test equipment (it's not a toy but it's for sports - the inside is basically a very narrow band Vector Network Analyser combined with an equally limited spectrum analyser/Software defined radio), which - if I understand correctly - grants an exemption.

It would be sold just as the sensor(à la test equipment), would it be tested as sold or would it need to be EMC tested as it is intended to be used (I'm not yet sure whether this particular example would pass or not in the sense that it isn't a radio transceiver but that's's a different a question)?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you intend to sell a consumer device, or a sensor component for people that *build* consumer devices?

Comment: It's a consumer device i.e. it's a complete assembly with a connector, but the thing it connects to is provided by the end user/s (so it's a bit like T&M gear but not quite).

Comment: if it's a consumer device it's not test gear, end of story, as far as I know... Just like say, a scanner is a consumer device, even if it measures a picture and is connected to a user-supplied PC.

Comment: That's not really what I was asking but I guess that's that cleared up - the FCC's website doesn't seem to have a specific definition of test equipment although I guess it's probably a case of if you have to ask they won't pick up the phone.

Comment: If you equipment is intended for use with something that it energizes and can radiate like an antenna, your equipment should be designed to satisfy the FCC limits on radiated EM while in use - you may be asked to provide a sample of those metal objects you would use your equipment with for FCC test.